# Create and Delete per shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is the Scenario:

I have an Java applet which shows the Cronjobs running on my Server. Now I want to create and delete Cronjobs out of the applet. The communication between the applet and the server is not a problem ,but I'm not quite sure how to create the Cronjobs per script so that I can delete them easily when I want to.

In my mind I have an own directory for each cronjob so that i can delete one by one if I want to.

I'm thankful for every suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a script that calls crontab -e without you doing something.
When you have full copies of the crontab, first remove the old cron.

```
$ crontab -r
$ export TERM=vt100; crontab -e >/dev/null 2>&1 <<@
:r /full/path/to/your/cronfile
:wq
@
$ crontab -l
```

Try this from the commandline. When your editCron.sh script works, call it.

EDIT: Above replaces the complete crontab, assuming you know exactly which version you want.
When you want to delete/add one line, you should make a script that edits the new cronfile. It is most easy when you try to remove the line you want to add,
so you do not have to think if the line already exists.
When you know a unique substring in your crontab line, make 2 files for each crontab line:

```
$ cat example.key
example.sh
$ cat example.cron
10 * * * * /var/local/bin/example.sh >/dev/null 2>@1
```

You can make and use an addcronline.sh script like this (not tested):

```
$ cat addcronline.sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo Usage: $0 key
   echo key: basename of a file in cronlines
   exit 1
fi

myCrons=/path/to/your/cronsnippets
keyFromApplet=$1
keyInCronline=$(cat ${myCrons}/${keyFromApplet}.key)
newCron=/full/path/to/your/cronfile

# Get current crontab and delete line when it's part of it
# In sed do not use / but #, since / can easily be port of your key
crontab -l | sed 's#'"${keyInCronline}"'##' > ${newCron}
cat ${myCrons}/${keyFromApplet}.cron >> ${newCron}
echo "Continue as the first code example (starting with crontab -r)"

$ chmod +x addcronline.sh

$ ./addcronline.sh example
```

When you have simple keys, you can simplify above script. You can use your parameter $1 directly as `keyInCronline` and you can remove the example.key file.

Comment: save a copy of your existing crontab before, with `crontab -l >/tmp/myCrontab.$(date +%Y%m%d)`. Good luck.

Comment: @Walter A: Maybe i'm wrong but when i use the crontab -e command all cronjobs would be written in the user's crontab ?! So that was my actual problem. I though it would be easier if i create for every new cronjob a file in a directory the cron deamon is looking for jobs. So when i want to delete a certain cronjob i just have to find the right file and delete it.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the `crontab in file` in your question was the complete crontab (all scheduled commands) and not one file per command. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion:

Look at the directory `/etc/cron.d` on your linux machine. There you probably find existing cron jobs that can be taken as templates for your task.

Next question is whether your applet has rights to create, modify and delete files in `/etc/cron.d`. Since I don't know more details on your situation, I cannot tell...

Comment: i have a servlet which recieves the new cronjob created by the applet. So it wouldn't be the applet working on the server. The syntax of a cronjob is not the problem. I just though the servlet could create for each new cronjob a file in a directory where the cron deamon is looking for new jobs. So when i have to delete a cronjob, i just have to look for the right file. When i use the crontab -e command all cronjobs are writing in one single file, so it would make the deleting of a certain job more difficult. At least that is that what i though.

Comment: that's why I pointed to `/etc/cron.d` - there you can place multiple files, each of them with one cron-job in it.